# How to show that the set $X_1$ = {$(x,y) \in R^2$ : $x$ , $y$ are irrationals} is not locally compact?

Tags: general-topology

How to show that the set $X_1$ = {$(x,y) \in R^2$ : $x$ , $y$ are irrationals} is not locally compact?
I think I have to show there does not exist any compact subset in $X_1$ which is not finite.

I am confused. Can anyone please give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

A metric set is called to be locally compact if there exist a neighborhood at any point of it that is compact. Since compactness requires boundedness and closedness (and a neighborhood is always bounded given a metric d) we only have to check closedness. Define $\epsilon$-neighborhood of (x,y) as $B_{\epsilon}$={$(u,v)$|$d((x,y),(u,v))\lt\epsilon$}. Assume decimal representations of x and y to be $a_{0}.a_{1}a_{2}a_{3}...$ and $b_{0}.b_{1}b_{2}b_{3}...$ respectively. Now for some natural k define $p_{n}$ as n repetitions of $a_{1}a_{2}...a_{k}$ after decimal point and the rest digits of $p_{n}$ as the rest digits of x and $q_{n}$ as well due to $b_{0}.b_{1}b_{2}b_{3}...$ meanwhile $p_{n}=a_{1}a_{2}...a_{k}a_{1}a_{2}...a_{k}...a_{1}a_{2}...a_{k}$(n times)$a_{nk+1}a_{nk+2}a_{nk+3}...$ and $q_{n}=b_{1}b_{2}...b_{k}b_{1}b_{2}...b_{k}...b_{1}b_{2}...b_{k}$(n times)$b_{nk+1}b_{nk+2}b_{nk+3}...$. k could be taken large enough so that $p_{n}$ and $q_{n}$ lie in $B_{\epsilon}$. Since the couple $(p_{n},q_{n})$ is irrational for any n and tend to some rational (p,q) that doesn't belong to $B_{\epsilon}$ then $B_{\epsilon}$ is not closed and is not compact as well.

Comment: Please mention ambiguations once you found 'em.